# What algorithm to use?

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that contains 18k samples and has only product names. Product names could be in Ukrainian, or Russian languages. Also, some products represent different products in English, e.g. IPhone or more complicated structure. I need to use clusterization algorithms to make different groups of products.

To normalize data I removed digits, commas, points, and other unnecessary symbols; translated from Russian to Ukrainian as much as possible using deep-translator, because Google API doesn't work, and applied lemmatization.

I tried using TF-IDF and DBSCAN/K-Means. DBSCAN found about 300 categories and almost 13k samples are assigned to only one category, but it's obvious that product names have different categories. So other 5k samples are distributed well. Let's name this anomaly cluster/category as MIXED because it contains different product categories. The same problem with K-means when I specify the number of clusters. I tried increasing number of clusters and it reduces amount of samples in the MIXED cluster. I used 2000 as the maximum number of clusters and it reduced amount of samples up to 5000 samples, but it's still bad results. I don't think that increasing the number of clusters is an optimal solution.

Then, I tried Spacy Library. Installed uk_core_news_lg and used .vector property for word embedding. This approach reduced the number of features in vectors from 10k(TF-idf) to 300. Fitting K-means on such vectors helped but sometimes I can find a lot of building materials in clusters that clearly represent some food category.

How can I improve models? Should I try something else?

Right now, I am thinking of using TF-IDF with k-means(n_clusters=100), removing data with MIXED category, and applying K-means on that removed data. If necessary - repeat these steps.

Comment: I would recommend reading more into cluster analysis and optimizing the number of clusters (hyperparameter optimization) by looking at metrics such as silhouette score. 

In K-Means, this can be done using scree plots. DBSCAN is not only notoriously computationally expensive but also very sensitive to the different hyperparameters giving a large amount of noise points or disproportionally sized clusters.

Lastly, you should look for any scaling or distribution issues with your data first before attempting any unsupervised learning.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I used the hierarchical clustering approach and it slightly improved the situation. I found some additional data with categories. I used T-SNE on the vectorized text and found out that some categories overlap each other so I think it's not possible to have a lower number of categories. But I will try hyperparameter tuning in the hope that it will combine some similar clusters, e.g. corn and milk could be one cluster - `food`.